# Why is there always an empty string at the end of this HtmlNodeCollection?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I wrote a method that will return all the tags from a Stack Overflow question. The only problem is that the last item in the collection is always an empty string.

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetQuestionTags(string url)
{
    var document = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new HtmlWeb().Load(url));
    var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"question\"]/table//tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[2]//a");
    return nodes.Select(node => node.InnerText);
}
```

I *could* simply remove the last item in the collection every time, but I'd like to not have to do that.

Why is there always an empty string as the last item in the collection, and how could I NOT retrieve that item?

Comment: There's another link you're selecting; `edit tags`. I'd imagine since you don't have 10,000 reputation, the text is blank. Make it select the span and *then* `a` for just the tags. Or, use the SE API. Here's the extra item you're selecting: http://i.imgur.com/coCLCVl.png

Comment: You can try to add a predicate to avoid selecting empty `<a>` element : `....//a[normalize-space()]`

Comment: @Rob The edit-tags-wrapper span doesn't exist for me...

Comment: @har07 That works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer...

You can use `normalize-space()` in predicate to *filter out* empty elements i.e those containing whitespaces only or contains nothing at all :

```
var xpath = "//*[@id='question']/table//tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[2]//a[normalize-space()]";
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
```